# Cleaning up Rake cucumber tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rake, task

I'm using Cucumber through rake and find myself repeating code when making extra tasks for cucumber. Is there a way to simplify/slim down the following:

```
...
  namespace :cucumber do
    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({:ok => 'db:test:prepare'}, 'Run features that should pass') do |t|
      t.binary = vendored_cucumber_bin # If nil, the gem's binary is used.
      t.fork = true # You may get faster startup if you set this to false
      t.profile = 'default'
    end

    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({:report => 'db:test:prepare'}, 'Run features that should pass') do |t|
      t.binary = vendored_cucumber_bin # If nil, the gem's binary is used.
      t.fork = true # You may get faster startup if you set this to false
      t.profile = 'report'
    end

    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({:report_pdf => 'db:test:prepare'}, 'Run features that should pass') do |t|
      t.binary = vendored_cucumber_bin # If nil, the gem's binary is used.
      t.fork = true # You may get faster startup if you set this to false
      t.profile = 'report_pdf'
    end

    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({:wip => 'db:test:prepare'}, 'Run features that are being worked on') do |t|
      t.binary = vendored_cucumber_bin
      t.fork = true # You may get faster startup if you set this to false
      t.profile = 'wip'
    end

    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({:new => 'db:test:prepare'}, 'Run all new features that are being worked on') do |t|
      t.binary = vendored_cucumber_bin
      t.fork = true # You may get faster startup if you set this to false
      t.profile = 'new'
    end

    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({:new_report => 'db:test:prepare'}, 'Run all new features that are being worked on') do |t|
      t.binary = vendored_cucumber_bin
      t.fork = true # You may get faster startup if you set this to false
      t.profile = 'new_report'
    end

    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({:new_report_pdf => 'db:test:prepare'}, 'Run all new features that are being worked on') do |t|
      t.binary = vendored_cucumber_bin
      t.fork = true # You may get faster startup if you set this to false
      t.profile = 'new_report_pdf'
    end

    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({:rerun => 'db:test:prepare'}, 'Record failing features and run only them if any exist') do |t|
      t.binary = vendored_cucumber_bin
      t.fork = true # You may get faster startup if you set this to false
      t.profile = 'rerun'
    end
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
namespace :cucumber do
  [[:ok, 'default'], :report, :report_pdf, :wip, :new, :new_report, :new_report_pdf, :rerun].each do |key|
    if key.is_a?(Array)
      profile = key[1]
      key = key[0]
    else
      profile = key.to_s
    end

    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({key => 'db:test:prepare'}, 'Run features that should pass') do |t|
      t.binary = vendored_cucumber_bin # If nil, the gem's binary is used.
      t.fork = true # You may get faster startup if you set this to false
      t.profile = profile
    end
  end
end
```